# Is it possible to build a (1/a*s+b) subsystem block with individual blocks in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to build a subsystem in simulink with 3 inputs and those would be 2 constants (a and b coefficients) and the input signal (a step, for example). And inside the block it should work as a transfer function (1/as+b).

I've tried somethings but the one I built only works as (1/s+b) and  I can't add the "a" coefficient.

[image: This works as (1/s+b) and the "b" is the "Ki1" block]

Is it possible to create this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using these blocks:

[image]